# How to use Sass in blazor?

Tags: css, sass, blazor

I found [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-preprocessor-support) about Css in razor. But it isn't work with Scss file.

I resolve this problem by creating two files: css and scss. And use sass --watch. But I need write this every time, when creating new component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately SASS is not supported for CSS Isolation feature of Blazor. At least, not at this moment.

In our project, we use CSS Isolation for the CSS component isolation feature, but we use SASS files to manage our theme, for style we want accros the application.

That being said, if you really need some SASS for an unique component, you totally can, by adding for example a wrapper with a specified id, and use this id in your scss file, with a dedicated name for it, for example `MyComponent.scss`.

In addition, I've found this article, but I preferred to not use it because it is  a bit heavy to setup, but up to you: https://joren-thijs.medium.com/how-to-add-scss-support-to-blazor-cd2a62995441

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AspNetCore.SassCompiler](https://github.com/koenvzeijl/AspNetCore.SassCompiler) which supports both normal and isolated scss. I believe it has a watch mode when using Blazor Server, WASM is not supported yet.

It can also do minification with source mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various ways to compile sass to css... In my opinion the fastest approach is using WebCompiler (Visual Studio extension), but I don't know if it is the best

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)